# How to make a widget maximum size be equal to the flex value in a row

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, row

I have this small code:

```dart
Container(
  color: Colors.blue,
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: const Text('Red text that can be long long long long long'),
        ),
      ),
      Flexible(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: const Text('Small text'),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

which renders into this:

[image]

Notice how the long text is wrapped even though there is still space around the small text.

I would like the small text to only take the size it needs to let the long text take the rest. And if the small text becomes bigger, its maximum size would be the size of the `Flexible` widget in the row (half of the `Row` in my example since both `Expanded` and `Flexible` have `flex: 1`).

If the small text is small enough, it should look like:

```
| Red text that can be long long long long | Small text |
| long                                     |            |
```

And if the "small" text is long too:

```
| Red text that can be long | Small text that is also  |
| long long long long       | very long                |
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Removing the flexible would do the job

Comment: @VinamraJaiswal Removing it will not prevent it to take all the length of the `Row` if the "small" text is too long. Here I want it to be half of the `Row` maximum (or whatever is the `flex` fraction).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ConstrainedBox:constraints: BoxConstraints.loose( Size.fromWidth(maxWidth / 2)` for green.

```dart
body:LayoutBuilder( 
  builder: (context, constraints) => Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: const Text(
              'Red text that can be long long long lbe long long long lbe long long long long long'),
        ),
      ),
      ConstrainedBox(
        constraints: BoxConstraints.loose(
            Size.fromWidth(constraints.maxWidth / 2)),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: const Text('Smalled g long th xt'),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 1):

In the end, I used [Yeasin Sheikh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10157127/yeasin-sheikh)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71036174/12066144) so I'm validating it.

But I'm writing this comment to add more precisions on what I have found during my investigations.

---

At first, I wanted a simple widget like `Flexible` or `Expanded` (let's say `LooseFlexible`) to wrap my widget with:

```dart
Container(
  color: Colors.blue,
  child: Row(
    children: [
      Expanded(
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: const Text('Red text that can be long long long long long'),
        ),
      ),
      LooseFlexible(
        flex: 1
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.green,
          child: const Text('Small text'),
        ),
      ),
    ],
  ),
),
```

but it seems it would go against the way Flutter works.

I took a look a the flutter class `RenderFlex`, which is the render object the `Flex` class (a class that `Row` and `Column` are extending) returns in the method `createRenderObject`.
It has a method `_computeSizes`, and inside it goes through the children (one by one):

- if it does not have a `flex` value (*"normal widget"*):
  It gives to the child no max constraint for the layout and gets its size.
- if it has a `flex` value (from `Flexible` or `Expanded`):
  it accumulates in a `totalFlex` value the some of all the `flex` (and **does not** render the child).

Then it goes through all the widgets that have a `flex` value and gives them as a max constraint `(flex / totalFlex) * (maxConstraintOfParent - totalSizeOfNonFlexChildren)` and layout them with it.

So each child is layout **only once**.

---

If my widget `LooseFlexible` were to exist, and if we had this code:

```dart
Row(
  children: [
    Expanded(flex: 1),
    LooseFlexible(flex: 1),
    Expanded(flex: 1),
  ],
),
```

Let's say the row has a `maxWidth` of `300`. There is no non-flex children and `totalFlex = 3`.

1. The 1st `Expanded` would be laid out with a `maxWidth = 100`. Since it is an `Expanded` its `width` will be `100`.
2. The `Flexible` widget is also laid out with a `maxWidth = 100`. But its size could be `50` (and not `100`).
3. Now comes the turn of the last `Expanded`, if we want it to take the entire remaining space, its size would be `150` which is not the same as the 1st `Expanded` with the same `flex = 1` value. So the first child would need to be re-laid out, which is not following the flutter way of rendering children only once.