# How to make the Row Flexible and auto resize it's elements

Tags: flutter

For example i have the following simple code

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return
        const Row(
          children: [
            Flexible(
              child: Text(
                'looooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong',
                maxLines: 1,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellowAccent),
              ),
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: Text(
                'looooooong',
                maxLines: 1,
                overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        );
  }
```

output
[image]

as you can see my row is not smart enough to expanding the yellow text as long as it possible,
it seem that it gave the two texts fixed spaces where i want to avoid it and make it more smart so it can take any empty space for longer text and expand it ..

when i remove the second  Flexible the it solve the issue but at the same time it will cause overflow for blue text if it was long too !!

my elements come from server and they are not fixed , so i favor to use flexible but with solving the empty space :|

in the fact i want do this to any elements in rows and not only text

Comment: Does it answer your question ? (Also, would it be a duplicate?) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71035632/how-to-make-a-widget-maximum-size-be-equal-to-the-flex-value-in-a-row. Here is the _"in depth"_ explanation https://stackoverflow.com/a/71050495/12066144

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the `Flexible` from second Text widget.

```dart
 Row(
  children: [
    Flexible(
      child: Text(
        'loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong',
        maxLines: 1,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellowAccent),
      ),
    ),
    Text(
      'looooooong',
      maxLines: 1,
      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
    ),
  ],
)
```

Comment: Oops , i just edit my question for this use case

Comment: if i remove it + if the blue text was long it will cause overflow :| , my elements in Row are not always fixed ,

Answer (score 0):

You can give `flex: 2` property to first `Flexible` widget. Did you try that?

```
Row(
  children: [
    Flexible(
      flex: 2,
      child: Text(
        'loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong',
        maxLines: 1,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.yellowAccent),
      ),
    ),
    Flexible(
      flex: 1,
      child: Text(
       'looooooong',
        maxLines: 1,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```